# Using MERN stack and nginx, I have deployed my website but I can't see images on my server

Tags: node.js, nginx, mern, multer, nginx-config

I am trying to add profile pictures to my crud apps. I've used multer to upload them to my server. Locally everything works fine. On deploy though, the source in inspect element is staying at `localhost:8000/uploads/{fileName.png}`. I also can't access the image at [http://myURL.com/uploads/{fileName.png}](http://myURL.com/uploads/%7BfileName.png%7D). I know it has to do with my nginx config, namely the `location /uploads` part, but I can't quite nail it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# crudApps Configuration 06-04-2023
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name crudApps;
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /uploads {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        alias /server/public/uploads;
    }
    location /socket.io/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    error_page 404 /index.html;
}
```

I've tried a number of variations of that path in the aforementioned section of my nginx config, I tried using both my URL and localhost:8000 as the proxy_pass, and tried without a proxy_pass. My images will not view at [http://url.com/uploads/{fileName.png}](http://url.com/uploads/%7BfileName.png%7D) the way they view locally at localhost:8000/uploads/{fileName.png}

---

Not sure what changed but it works now.